# How to describe the flow of an hourglass

Tags: description

I'm thinking of somewhat of a poetic way to describe how time flows, via an hourglass. Does sand simply 'flow' through an hourglass? Drip doesn't sound applicable, and 'stream' is just basically flow.

Basically, what's another applicable word to describe sand moving through an hourglass?

Comment: asking to identify a word or a phrase is off-topic here, but you may have better luck asking on the [English site](english.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I think **flow** and **stream** are two good choices, because they simply give the reader a clear idea and mental image of what you're describing.

But here's some others, for the sake of poetic charm:

- gush
- drizzle
- pour
- sprinkle
- leak
- run (running through)

Hope I could be of a little help, and good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I think slip was the word I was looking for. The other ones feel too watery for a description for sand.

Comment: Sifting? Bleeding? As in "watching time bleeding sand through its glass vein"?

Comment: @A.Lau Since you won't be referring to the consistency or texture of the sand so much as its movement, which is similar to a running stream, I don't think you should shy away from a potentially "watery" description.

Comment: @Lew Nice, I like that!